# Passing variables from HTML to Javascript file that uses addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, django, stripe-payments, addeventlistener

I'm using Stripe to accept Apple pay payments (not super important here). I'm using Django. The code works fine for processing the payments, but I'm having trouble passing in a variable to my separate .js file. (amount to charge) from my HTML file to the Javascript file that actually processes the payments.

**home.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    import more scripts here
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'interface/utils.js' %}" defer></script>
    <script src="{% static 'interface/apple-pay.js' %}" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="text-center">
        <div id="rectangle"></div>
    </header>
    <section>
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="container container--narrow">
                <script>amount=parseInt("{{event.price}}")</script>
                <div id="payment-request-button">
                    <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here if the browser supports this type of payment method. -->
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

The Javascript file that gets called to process the payment:
**apple-pay.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_testkey');

    const paymentRequest = stripe.paymentRequest() ({
        currency: 'usd',
        country: 'US',
        requestPayerName: true,
        requestPayerEmail: true,
        total: {
            label: 'Test payment',
            amount: amount, //trying to pass the variable in here
        }
    });

  // Other functions that get called go here
});
```

The error I see in the console is that 'total' in the API call is no longer an object. Console.log(typeof amount) returns a number and console.log(amount) returns the number I expect. But how do I pass that to the Javascript file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data` attributes. The way you're currently doing it could theoretically work if you rigged it up just right, but it's definitely not the best practice. An easy solution is:

Instead of this code,

```
<script>amount=parseInt("{{event.price}}")</script>
```

just attach a `data-amount` attribute to an element near the tree. You might even be able to get away with putting it on the `payment-request-button` like this:

```
<div id="payment-request-button" data-amount="{{event.price}}">
```

Then in your javascript:

```js
//...
    amount: parseInt(document.querySelector("#payment-request-button").dataset.amount)
//...
```

If you can't edit the javascript file then things are a lot more complicated, so I hope you can!